# Put text in helper method, but the caluclation is in float

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I have a helper method for some calculations, I want to put some text but when I call this method the after calculation is in float.
I want to put text how can I do this?

```
if m == e
   0.0
 elsif e == 0
  put "not defined"    
 else
  (m - e)/e
 end
```

Any idea? thanks!

Comment: You mean that you need result as a `string`?

Comment: just call your method and `.to_s`

Comment: try this - http://codepad.org/gLUci2gB

Comment: but then when I have numbers instead of string is messed up

Comment: Explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I am trying to put not defined in a table cell, but the value there is calculated in float. So I want the text somehow to be in float.

Answer (score 0):

```
if m == e
  '0'
elsif e == 0
  put "not defined"    
else
  ((m - e)/e).to_s
end
```

Look [Ruby in Twenty Minutes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/)

Comment: I need it in float because I have other methods calling for this that are in float

Comment: for example --ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `abs' for "0.00040187665997814886"

Comment: @Nda.S where you need it as `String`, call that method with `to_s`. Example:  Suppose your method name is `foo`, call it as `foo.to_s`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your helper method name is `foo`

If you want to convert its return type to `String` for a particular method call, then method can be invoked like `foo.to_s`

In other places where you need the result as `Float`, just call it as `foo` .

Comment: The problem is that I call this method just 1 time for both cases.

Comment: @Nda.S I think it would be better to understand  if you could add relevant codes to your question. How you are currently calling the method, what result you are getting and what result you are expecting.